# Solve the differential equation: $y'+3y=2xe^{ -3x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $y'+3y=2xe^{-3x}$.

I found the integrating factor to be $e^{\int 3dx}=e^{3x}$.

This leads to $3ye^{3x}=2x^2/2+c$, which leads to $y = \dfrac{x^2+c}{3e^{3x}}$.

The answer is $y(x) = e^{−3x} (x^{2} + C)$.

I cannot see how they got rid of the 3 in the denominator. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If the integrating factor is $e^{3x}$ there should be no $3$ on the left hand side after integrating

Comment: @NinadMunshi why would the 3 be gone on the LHS? I thought the integrating factor just multiplied through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{3x} y' + e^{3x} (3y)= 2x$$
$$\implies e^{3x} y' + (3e^{3x}) y = 2x$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} (e^{3x} y)= 2x$$
$$\implies e^{3x} y = \frac{x^2}{2} + c$$

Comment: Basically, check if the LHS can be written in the form $f'g + fg'$ so that it can be written as $(fg)'$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you try to solve it, but for a linear diff equation with inhomogeneity you can also try to solve the homogeneous equation first, then use variation of the constant method.

**homogeneous equation**

$$
y'+3y = 0, \quad y' = -3y
$$

is obviously solved by $y(x)=C e^{-3x}$.

**inhomogeneous equation**

We make the variation of constant ansatz $y(x)=C(x)e^{-3x}$. Putting into the equation you get

$y'+3y=C' e^{-3x}-3y + 3y=C' e^{-3x}$

which has to equal to $2xe^{-3x}$, thus $C'=2x$, from where we know $C(x)=x^2+c$. This gives the general solution $y(x)=(x^2+c)e^{-3x}$.

Comment: I tried using an integrating factor. I have seen the method you show in class, but this particular textbook question calls for the use of an integrating factor.

Answer (score 1):

After finding the integrating factor correctly, you now need to multiply through by it. This gives

$$y' e^{3x} + 3y e^{3x} = 2x. $$

Now the left side is just a result of the product rule, so rewrite as

$$ \left( y e^{3x} \right)' = 2x $$

from whence the result follows. Your mistake was introducing an artificial $3$.